# Optimizations for new SQL Server 2000 database that will act as email queue AND API database

Tags: sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2000, queue

Due to limitations put on me I've got to put my outgoing Email Queue in the same database as my customer information.

What are some optimizations I can make, specifically to the Email portion that will make this process smoother:

- Grab emails where "sending" is set to False
- Set "sending" on all those records to True
- Process them one at a time, if they fail mark "sending" to False on the record
- If they succeed, delete the record and add a new one to "Email Archive" table

This process will run once every 5 minutes. At the moment there will only be one app sending the emails but in the future there may be more.

Comment: Why do new development on SQL 2000? Put some pressure on leadership to get up to date.

Comment: @brian : It's not an option and has already been discussed with leadership.

Comment: If you're absolutely stuck with 2000, have you looked into using SQL Mail instead of reinventing the wheel? (I can't believe I just suggested that -- make sure your code is easily modifiable to work with Database Mail if and when you upgrade.)